# Rails nested form with simple form not showing nested objects' form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, simple-form

I've got a rails update form like this:

```
<%= debug @ballot.scores %>
<%= simple_form_for(@ballot, :url => "/vote/#{@election.id}/ballot/#{@ballot.position}/submit", :method => :post, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :scores do |builder| %>
    <div class="slider">Slider goes here!</div>
    <%= builder.hidden_field :initialValue, :value => 50 %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The debug shows:

```
---
- !ruby/object:Score
  attributes:
    id: 1
    ballot_id: 4
    candidate_id: 4
    initialScore: 
    normalizedScore: 
    created_at: 2013-08-08 05:00:10.391163000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-08-08 05:00:10.432374000 Z
- !ruby/object:Score
  attributes:
    id: 2
    ballot_id: 4
    candidate_id: 5
    initialScore: 
    normalizedScore: 
    created_at: 2013-08-08 05:00:10.418904000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-08-08 05:00:10.434772000 Z
```

So there are definitely score objects, however no "Slider goes here!" text is showing up on the page.  Why isn't this working?

Let me know if you need more info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `<%= fields_for ...` you are missing the `=` sign.

Try:

```
<%= f.fields_for :scores do |builder| %>
```

Please refer to [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) documentation on it's usage.

Although `fields_for` works regardless of use of simple_form, you could use `simple_fields_for` as well since you are using simple_form as follows:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :scores do |builder| %>
```